# How to make a URL that links to the defect?

Tags: rally

I'm working on a custom defect list that is using the 1.26 SDK. I'm trying to include a field that will have the actual link to bring up the defect details. (e.g. The link should look something like: https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/14687805735d/detail/defect/UNIQUEDEFECTNUMBER with UNIQUEDEFECTNUMBER obviously replaced with the ObjectID).

I did some searching and saw that the Rally.nav.Manager might be something of interest, but it's only supported by 2.0+ SDK, and I think I need to keep this in 1.26 to preserve the integrity of the work that's already been done. Is there a way that I can create a URL with it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var defectObjectID = results.defects[i].ObjectID;
var defectURL = rally.sdk.util.Navigation. createRallyDetailUrl("/defect/" + defectObjectID, true);
```

See https://help.rallydev.com/navigation for details.